# /usr/lib/libblkid.so.1: version BLKID_2_37 can not found

Tags: archlinux

When I restarted my computer after updating my arch linux, I encounter this problem, does anyone know how to fix it?
The picture below is the error message that is reported when I start my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this happen to me today and finally managed to fix it - and to give a bit of context to anyone who happens to stumble into the same issue in the future, I was trying to install a driver meant for an earlier version of linux onto the current 5.10 and 5.4 LTS (in Manjaro).

Anyway, assuming my steps would help you, I am going to list them out below as best as I can:

- Make a bootable USB of any Linux distro you would like (I used an older Manjaro ISO I had on hand and used YUMI for the USB creation)
- Boot to the USB
- Identify your problematic installation's root and mount it somewhere ( I used `/mnt`.
- Chroot into the mount point as root: `# chroot /mnt /bin/sh` (At this point you may get some errors with somethings like networking (such as resolv.conf being wrong) - but that should be a fairly easy google search away from a fix)
- Upgraded my entire system, since my package manager is pacman, I used `# pacman -Syu`
- If any package conflicts come up - you would have to resolve them.

Once the process is completed, unmount and reboot to the original Linux installation and hopefully it should all be fine.